# Android -what is the Common way to implement a server

Tags: android

I would like to build a Server for my Android Application whats needs to send and receive Strings.
It seems to me that The Client should look something like:

```
        // Try to connect to the Server
        serverConnection = new Socket(serverIP, 4444);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(serverConnection.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(serverConnection.getOutputStream());
        ...
        ... // use ois/oos for further communication with the server
        ...
        serverConnection.close();
```

But what bothers me is what is the "**REAL WOLD**" practice of building the Server? I.e what language to implement it with? , what is the reason for choosing this language?

Comment: Is sending over strings all you would like to do? If so, wouldn't a webserver be sufficient?

Comment: All i need from my server is sending back data like meetings, user data, and so on... [this could all be translated into strings]